# Setting the value of TextView from the separate thread with the help of Handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading

**UPD**

I have the code of class:

```
package asus.example.com.player;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private Button prev;
    private Button next;
    private Button play;
    private Snackbar snackbar;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private TextView curTime;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private final int SONG_LENGTH = 120;

    View.OnClickListener snackbarOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    };


    private void onPrevClick(final View view){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Prev", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Close", snackbarOnClickListener);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }

    private void onPlayClick(final View view){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int secs = seekBar.getProgress()*SONG_LENGTH/100;
                while (secs<=SONG_LENGTH) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    seekBar.setProgress(secs/SONG_LENGTH*100);
                    secs++;
                }
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }

    private void onNextClick(final View view){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Next", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Close", snackbarOnClickListener);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prev = findViewById(R.id.prev);
        play = findViewById(R.id.play);
        next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        curTime = findViewById(R.id.curTime);
        prev.setOnClickListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.prev:
                onPrevClick(v);
                break;
            case R.id.play:
                onPlayClick(v);
                break;
            case R.id.next:
                onNextClick(v);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        int seconds = (SONG_LENGTH*seekBar.getProgress()/100)%60;
        int minutes = (SONG_LENGTH*seekBar.getProgress()/100)/60;
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        String result = String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        curTime.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

    }
}
```

The main aim is to put the new value to `TextView` every second, while `secs<=SONG_LENGTH`. As I can't do it from the `thread`, I use `Handler` for it. When I had such a problem with `SnackBar` it helped me, but at this time program just stops. It doesn't close, but I can't click on any buttons, `SeekBar`. What's the problem and how can it be solved? And if it isn't hard for you - explain, please, why it worked well with `SnackBar`, but not with `TextView`?

Comment: I am not posting as an answer to wait for someone to explain in details what is wrong, but if you are stuck with this problem, you can use the runOnUiThread method from the Activity class to avoid needing to create a handler by your on.

Comment: you dont need any `Thread`s - just use repeatedly `Handler#postDelayed()` and `DateUtils#formatElapsedTime()` methods

Comment: @jonathanrz, I changed my code a little bit. Now I change the value of `textview` from the method `onProgressChanged`. So, I don't need to use `handler` for UI thread in such case, but it still doesn.t work. I'd attach the code of the class to the question

Comment: @pskink, sorry, but I understood only a part of your answer. What is method `DateUtils#formatElapsedTime()` for? I tried to do in another way, but it didn;t help. I refreshed the question.

Comment: what do you need String.format for?

Comment: @pskink, to add time to `textview` in format `1:03`, for example. 1 digit for minutes and 2 for seconds. And `:` between them

Comment: and have you read `DateUtils#formatElapsedTime()` method documentation?

Comment: @pskink, yes, thanks, I am reading about it now and it's really more suitable in my case, but I don't think that it'll help me,as I just get the same string, but in different ways

Comment: OK, then what kind of problems do you have now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186254/discussion-between-sergei-mikhailovskii-and-pskink).